# Attempting to access a types.reference(Model) before it's id is set for mobx-state-tree?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

Got a question. So I'm making a small app working with the github api (using mobx-state-tree and mobx). I'm brand new to both.

I'm having a problem: you see selectedRepo? If i set an id to it, I can access selectedRepo. However... if I attempt to access selectedRepo before I set an id to it, the application will break. I've tried wrapping it with types.optional, types.maybe, but no matter what it just will not work.

Any ideas?

```
const defaultState = {
  count: 10,
  githubToken: "",
  selectedRepo: ""
};

const Issue = types.model({
  id: types.identifier(types.number),
  title: types.string,
  body: types.string
});

const Repo = types.model({
  id: types.identifier(types.number),
  name: types.optional(types.string, ""),
  owner: types.optional(
    types.model({
      login: ""
    }),
    {}
  )
});

const AppStore = types
  .model({
    state: "done",
    githubToken: "",
    issues: types.optional(types.array(Issue), []),
    repos: types.optional(types.array(Repo), []),
    selectedRepo: types.reference(Repo)
  })
```

Comment: I tried your code - works fine. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tf6q1LL1/ copy the code from here to https://mattiamanzati.github.io/mobx-state-tree-playground/ (make sure to go to the preview section)
i guess there is another problem not related to the model above

Comment: @RobinF that's a bit different from my code. I did end up resolving the issue using types.maybe though, that worked out great. Thanks.

Comment: @RobinF if you want to create an answer saying what you've changed, why mine breaks, I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: hah thats the thig - i didnt change anything :) i copy pasted your code into the sandbox. it might had been related to an older version of mst or other surrounding code in your env which i cant see above.